# Determine var type depending on ternary (?) Operator on int array

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion, ternary-operator

I have a string[] parameter which comes from a listbox. Depending on the users numbers of selection I want a var type to be assigned accordingly.

```
var intKonsoler = konsoler.Length > 1 ? konsoler.Select(int.Parse).ToArray() : int.Parse(konsoler[0]);
var intGenres = genres.Length > 1 ? genres.Select(int.Parse).ToArray() : int.Parse(genres[0]);
```

This obviously wont work and I get a :

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int[]' and 'int'
```

So what do I want to achive? I want the var to either be assigned as a int from the string[] if the string[] only contains one value, or a int[] with the values from the string[] if it contains several.

Comment: Why would you want that? Can't see the point.

Comment: While `var` allows you to do dynamic typing it still builds statically.  You cannot have a variable that has the possibility of being both `int` and `int[]`.

Comment: both sides of the ternary operator have to evaluate to the same type.  Even if you could do what you wanted here, how would you know what to do with it later? It doesn't make sense

Comment: @paqogomez `var` does not allow dynamic typing.  It requires entirely static typing.

Comment: @Servy, of course, you are correct.  I was trying to think of the right description, but dynamic typing of variables is not it.  Perhaps dynamic typing on the keyboard? lol

Comment: @paqogomez The term is implicit typing.

Comment: Isn't what I'm going to do with it rather irrelevant? It will be assigned accordingly depending of type, thanks for your inputs :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having a variable that is either an array of integers or a single integer, you should just unconditionally have an array of integers.  If you don't know if the variable is a single value or a collection of values you pretty much won't be able to use it.  If you know it's a collection, you can still use it effectively if its size is one.

Just have your second option create a one-item array inline:

```
var intKonsoler = konsoler.Length > 1 ? 
    konsoler.Select(int.Parse).ToArray() : 
    new[]{int.Parse(konsoler[0])};
```

Or, better yet, just remove the conditional check to see if the collection's length is one:

```
var intKonsoler = konsoler.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

There just isn't a reason to treat this collection  any differently (when performing this particular operation) if it's size is one.

Comment: Thanks for useful input, since the values of intKonsoler will populate a collection of propertys on another object, I thought it would be cleaner in the code to have this approach, but alas, I was wrong. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with if else?

```
dynamic intKonsoler;

if(konsoler.Length > 1)
{
    intKonsoler = konsoler.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
}
else
{
    inKonsoler = int.Parse(konsoler[0]);
}
```

Comment: nothing is wrong at all, I just want as clean code as I can... :-)

Comment: If you want `dynamic`, you can use `if` like above, or `? :` like in Mikko Viitala's answer. There is an implicit conversion from any type (not `unsafe` pointer types, I think) to `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

Straight answer: that's not possible.
Seems like you misunderstood the `var` keyword. It has nothing to do with the something like `Variant` in `COM` or some `VB` dialects. It is nothing but a convenient shortcut for longer type declarations (called *syntactic sugar*), and its concrete type has to be determined by the compiler at compile time.

In other words: What you are trying to do is exactly the same as writing

```
int intKonsoler = konsoler.Length > 1 ? konsoler.Select(int.Parse).ToArray() : int.Parse(konsoler[0]);
```

It's just plain wrong, I'm afraid...

**EDIT**:
Of course, you could use the `dynamic` keyword, as other answers state. But why would you want to do that? That would be against the whole idea of C# as a statically typed language.